# tortoisegit git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) push

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm getting this error message when I push local file to github:

[image: what's wrong?]

What's wrong?

Comment: I did't found the answer in google about tortoisegit,so I used gitbash to do this,finished!

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub repository contains commits you do no have locally. You need to fetch and merge these new commits from the server into your local repository first before pushing.

```
$ git pull
$ git push
```

Comment: I used gitbash not tortoisegit,and now it worked,thank you!